# Multiplication of lines of irrational length

Tags: geometric-construction

Suppose you are given two lines, each has length of an irrational number. How would one, using a straight-edge and compass, draw a line whose length is the product of the two given irrational numbers?

Edit: Yes, you are also given a unit line. But note that the irrational numbers are not necessarily square roots.

Comment: Are we given a unit line?  I guess not.  I feel a little ... sucker punched ... being told the lines are irrational without a unit reference.

Comment: If the numbers are equal I'd think it would be pretty easy to construct the square. Can you be a bit more specific? In what context is this?

Comment: It cannot be done without a unit length, or something equivalent.  With a unit length one uses similar triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Use similar triangles and the identity $\dfrac{rs}{r} = \dfrac{s}{1}$. You have 3 of the terms and want the 4th.

Comment: Note to the OP: the fact that the original lengths are irrational is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a segment $\overline{ACB}$ such that $AC = r$ and $CB = s$.

Construct a perpendicular through $C$, and mark off a point such that $CD = 1$.

Construct the circle $O$ through $A, B,$ and $D$.

Find the intersection point $E$ of $O$ and $\overline{CD}$.

Then by the power of a point theorem, $CE = rs$.

Comment: Yup this is a nice way too.